# Can't rotate about the pivot

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am trying to insert a new value into an `AVL` tree. The new insertion causes imbalance (as per the article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avl_tree), this should belong to the left-right case), hence needs rotation. However, it is not possible to rotate in the current situation, since both children end up in becoming lesser than a parent:

```
           15
         /    \
        10    27
       /  \      
      8   12
```

Now if I want to insert 11, the structure becomes imbalanced:

```
           15
         /    \
        10    27
       /  \      
      8   12
         /
        11
```

Since the left subtree is longer, and the left subtree has a longer right subtree, as per the Wikipedia diagrams, this should fall under the Left-Right case. However, there, the element `4` had both left and right subtrees, making the rotation possible. but here, since `12` has only the left subtree, rotation makes it look like:

```
           15
         /    \
        12    27
       /  \      
      10   8
         /
        11
```

resulting in both children of `12` being less than 12. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be rotating wrong. The only node with the wrong balance factor is the root, so you rotate around that.

That case involves checking the balance factor of `10` (left child of the root): it is -1, so we need two different rotations (left-right case).

First, we rotate around 10 to the left, as per the upper left part of this image:

[image]

So we get:

```
           15
          /  \
         12  27
        / 
       10    
      /  \
     8   11
```

Then you continue with the next rotation as described in the image.